# csv long table in landscape

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple, lscape

I want to import a csv table, but the table has too many columns i.e. too wide. So I put it in landscape environment and use the `\csvautolongtable`. The specific code is the following:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{landscape}
\csvautolongtable{rforest_result.csv}
\end{landscape}
```

However, the table does not span on different pages. Can some one help me with that? Thanks in advance!
Allen
[image]

## Update:

The table have 34 columns but it only prints 20 columns as you can see from the attachment. It does not extend to the next page as you would expect for a `\csvautolongtable`

Comment: it is very hard to see the problem as your question has no usable example, but do you mean that the table has only 25 or so rows but too many columns to fit even landscape? if so then probably you need to break it by hand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will clarify my questions. Sorry that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just updated my question. Yes, the table has only 21 rows but many columns. How can I break the csv table by hand?

Comment: please provide a MWE

Comment: The question is still lacking a usable example, but just use your editor to split the table into (say) three tables with 11 or 12 columns each and then typeset them with suitable subheadings, latex can not really do this as to split a table you really need to understand it to find sensible places to split.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Hi Peter, sorry I am new to the TexCommunity. What does MWE stand for?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I ended up breaking the csv manually. Since we can handle long table in portrait by `\csvautolongtable`. It just seems unintuitive to me that there is no solution in landscape. Anyway, problem solved. What should I do with this post? Answer my own question? Copy and paste your comment to be answer? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: MWE is http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/

Comment: answer own question I think, the fact that it doesn't do what you thought is probably helpful to next person who thinks that. The landscape env rotates the page but the longtable breaking still works to split between rows, so if you had lots of rows it would split giving a multipage landscape table. splitting between columns is a lot harder (especially if you allow the table to contain `\multicolumn`) a caption for example typically spans the whole table, hard to split that vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Davide Carlisle's help (see in the comment), the problem has been solved.

When using `\csvautolongtable` in landscape, it will not break the additional columns that exceed the page length, but it will still put the additional rows on the next page. I guess that's my misunderstanding regarding the `\csvautolongtable` in landscape environment.

I ended up manually break the wide csv into 2 and import them separately.

Thanks
Allen